# TradingView Pine script's time() function for weekends?

Tags: time, pine-script

I'm developing an indicator that shows custom time zone sessions by changing chart background.

For that I use this function to check if one bar is inside one of my defined time sessions:

```
InSession(sess) => na(time(period, sess)) == false
```

Where `sess` it's something similar to `"0130-0800"`.

But it's not drawing anything during the weekend. It seems that the `time()` function only checks its input on workdays. But I use this indicator in cryptocurrencies that are open every day.

Is there any way to extend the `time()` check to the weekends? If not, can you think of another method to check if a bar is within a timeframe?

PS: This is the full indicator code: https://es.tradingview.com/script/NMjZ2616/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only have to add the string `":1234567"` to the session hours to include weekends and `":12345"` to exclude weekends.

Sample code:

```
// InSession() determines if a price bar falls inside the specified session
InSession(sess) => na(time(period, sess)) == false

// === INPUTS ===
sessionHours=input(defval="0800-1400", type = session, title="Session Hours")
inputIncludeWeekends=input(title="Include Weekends?", type=bool, defval=true)

weekendsStr = inputIncludeWeekends ? ":1234567" : ":12345"

// === /INPUTS ===

bgcolor(color=InSession(sessionHours + weekendsStr)[1] ? red : na, title="Session Hours", transp=85)
```

Thanks to https://www.tradingview.com/u/pequet/

Comment: Could you mark this as the answer? That way this page doesn't show up on the 'unanswered' page, while it instead is fixed (right?)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to mark the day I answered it but it did not allow it. Maybe there is a time of lack. Thanks for the warning and for the corrections.

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío how configure all days. including weekends

Comment: Use '0000-2359:1234567'

Comment: saved so many headaches and found this excellent trick... thanks